# How do I pass arguments to a script added to the startup applications?

Tags: 12.04, startup

I want to start a script on startup, ideally at the end of boot process. To do this, I added it to the list of Startup Applications using the GUI. This is working fine.

However, I also want to pass it command line parameters on initialization. I tried adding it into the command itself within startup applications but that does not work. So, how do I pass the parameters on initialization?

Comment: Your script is in bash?

Comment: Yes @RaduRădeanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to have those arguments written in a file and then access that file from the script. For example, assuming that your script is a bash script and your file with arguments is something like:

```
a=7
b="foo"
c=$a
```

you can call these arguments in your script as follow:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

source /path/to/file_with_arguments

#just for test
echo $a
echo $b
echo $c

#your code script here
```